# Helm --force option

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I read in a book written by Helm creators the following fact about the --force option :

> Sometimes, though, Helm users want to make sure that the pods are restarted. That’s
> where the --force flag comes in. Instead of modifying the Deployment (or similar
> object), it will delete and re-create it. This forces Kubernetes to delete the old pods
> and create new ones.

What I understand from that is, if I install a chart and then I change the number of replicas (=number of pods) then I upgrade the chart, it should recreate all the pods. This is not what happens in my case and I wanted to understand what I am missing here.

Comment: Please provide more details. What have you tried? Which commands you used?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a hypothetical minimal Deployment (many required details omitted):

```yaml
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: abc:123
```

and you change this to *only* increase the replica count

```yaml
spec:
  replicas: 5 # <-- this is the only change
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: abc:123
```

The Kubernetes Deployment controller looks at this change and says "I already have 3 Pods running `abc:123`; if I leave those alone, and start 2 more, then I will have 5, and the system will look like what the Deployment spec requests".  So absent any change to the embedded Pod spec, the existing Pods will be left alone and the cluster will just scale up.

```
deployment-12345-aaaaa      deployment-12345-aaaaa
deployment-12345-bbbbb      deployment-12345-bbbbb
deployment-12345-ccccc ---> deployment-12345-ccccc
                            deployment-12345-ddddd
                            deployment-12345-eeeee
  (replicas: 3)               (replicas: 5)
```

Usually this is fine, since you're running the same image version and the same code.  If you do need to forcibly restart things, I'd suggest using `kubectl rollout restart deployment/its-name` rather than trying to convince Helm to do it.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your answer. I understand what you are telling but this force option is supposed to force Kubernetes to start everyting from scratch. Actually, this is not the case